# PHP Undefined variable css

Tags: php, css

Working on a contact form, seems like it displays the following error on the source code.

```
Undefined variable: css in...
```

The form works perfectly, but I dont know how to solve that issue.

One solution could be adding the following line to my php code:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

But ignoring the fact of hiding errors (for reasons that does not matter), I don't know if I am missing something because I can't understand at all php code.

PHP CODE:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
    {
    $success='<p>Thanks for contact us!<p>';
    $css='<style type="text/css">.demo-form{display:none;}.thanks{display:block;}</style>';
    unset($_SESSION['sent']);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
          <?=$css?>
        </head>
```

The error is on: `<?=$css?>`, because deleting that value, the contact-form keeps working, but the following part of the main code does not work: `.demo-form{display:none;}`, it just displays the `thanks` `div` without hiding the `.demo-form`.

VISUAL DEMO:

A- With: `<?=$css?>` (hides the `.demo-form`)

[image]

B -Without: `<?=$css?>` (does not hide `.demo-form`)

[image]

How could I make it work like the A example but without getting the php error?

Comment: `$css` won't be defined is there is no `$_SESSION['sent']`?

Comment: That's not a bug, but a feature... cfr previous remark.

Comment: I wouldn't hide such a message through CSS. If you are rendering the page anyway, just don't output it at all. Otherwise it might accidentally be shown or even indexed by search engines.

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree with your point, and it is a valid one, but I'm pretty sure search engines are mature enough now to detect hidden content. as people used to have hidden links for SEO value.

Comment: The problem comes when it is a one page website, and the success message just pops on the same page, not in another one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?= isset ($css) ? $css : ''?>
```

Check if a variable exists before using it. Alternatively, declare `$css = '';` at the start of your code.

Comment: I would go with your alternative solution: the initial declaration. Keeps the code cleaner. Inserting PHP variables in HTML is complex enough to read without having extra checks.